# Printing a stack with a "for" loop

Tags: java, stack

I am trying to **print the elements of stack S in reverse (using a "for" loop)**, but so far I haven't had any success.

I have managed to do it with "pop" fairly easily, but the second way evades me. My solution for "pop" is commented out at the end of the code.

Any help will be appreciated.

PS. Most of this code is irrelevant to the question, but if I knew what and where I can cut out, I probably wouldn't need help at all. Sorry.

```
package simplearraystackofchars;

public class SimpleArrayStackofchars implements Stack {

protected int capacity;     // The actual capacity of the stack array
public static final int CAPACITY = 2;   // default array capacity
protected Object S[], K[];      // Generic array used to implement the stack 
protected int top = -1; // index for the top of the stack (-1 = empty stack)

public SimpleArrayStackofchars() {
    this(CAPACITY); // default capacity 
}

public SimpleArrayStackofchars(int cap) {
    capacity = cap;
    S = new Object[capacity];
}

public int size() {
    return (top + 1);
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (top == -1);
}

public void push(Object element) throws FullStackException {
    if (size() == capacity) {
        //throw new FullStackException("Stack is full. Stack size max is "+ capacity);
        // can replace previous line with code to double stack size
        doubleArray();
    }
    S[++top] = element;
}

public Object top() throws EmptyStackException {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new EmptyStackException("Stack is empty.");
    }
    return S[top];
}

public Object pop() throws EmptyStackException {
    Object element;
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new EmptyStackException("Stack is empty.");
    }
    element = S[top];
    S[top--] = null; // dereference S[top] for garbage collection.
    return element;
}

private void doubleArray() {
    Object[] newArray;

    System.out.println("Stack is full (max size was " + capacity + "). Increasing to " + (2 * capacity));
    //double variable capacity
    capacity = 2 * capacity;
    newArray = new Object[capacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < S.length; i++) {
        newArray[i] = S[i];
    }
    S = newArray;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack S = new SimpleArrayStackofchars();

    S.push("1");
    S.push("2");
    S.push("3");
    S.push("4");
    S.push("5");
    S.push("6");

//      Stack K is created by popping elements of Stack S from the top.
//      This reverses the order.
//
//      Stack K = new SimpleArrayStackofchars();
//      while (!S.isEmpty()) {
//          K.push(S.pop());
//        }
//      while (!K.isEmpty()) {
//            System.out.println(K.pop());
//        }

    while (!S.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(S.pop());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please read this first: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: `for (; !S.isEmpty();) { System.out.println(S.pop()); }` is a legal `for` loop alternative to your `while` loop.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch I can't understand how to use it to reverse the stack then. Could you elaborate?

Comment: If you know the start and stop indices, and it's just an array, can't you just iterate and print?

Comment: I think that the SimpleArrayStackOfChars class should have a printReverse method that would iterate the array backwards and print. No encapsulation problems, no damage to the stack, no need for a second stack.

Answer (score 0):

```
Not really sure about what you need that for loop for, but this should produce the same result:
 Stack K = new SimpleArrayStackofchars();
 for (int i = 0, i < S.size(); i++) {
     K.push(S.pop());
 }
 for (int i = 0, i < K.size(); i++) {
     System.out.println(K.pop());
 }
```

Comment: Sure it does, but it didn’t seem to be a problem with the OPs “while” solution...

Comment: While it is a solution of some sort, it's honestly trying to game the system with a starter programmer's trick. I really do not think that is what is expected of me - rather, "pop" should be replaced by "for", not "while". That is the tricky part. I assume it should be somehow possible with Stack's inheritance from Vector or AbstractList, but I honestly have no clue how to approach it without getting zillions of errors. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: I think there’s a conceptual issue there. Good encapsulation states that no outside element should access the stack’s values if not by its public methods, therefore pop, push, and so on. You could add a peek(int index) method to access the given element in the stacks array, and then it would be easy to implement the for loop given you know it’s size. Or you could add a printReverse() method that does it from the inside. But no outer class should be able to access the Stack’s array.

Comment: I "assume" what you're describing is one the right ways to go, although it may just need me to abuse the poor encapsulation of Vector - I'm not sure. However, I am simply too bad to implement any of yoru suggestions. If you could give an example of peek() or printReverse() methods, I would be grateful. If it takes too much time - do not bother, I will bug my lecturer about this on Friday (although I do have a ton of other questions). In any case, thanks again!